# If string begins with XX then

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to show postcodes on my Wordpress site:

```
echo get_zip(get_the_ID())
```

Is there a way I can change what is outputted based on the first two or three letters, so for example, the postcode 'SW1-234' becomes "South West" and 'N1-456' becomes "North" etc. There are around 200 different postcode possibilities I want to change.

So far i have come up with this:

```
<?php $postcode = get_zip(get_the_ID());
      if(substr($postcode['id'],0,3) == 'N1'){
      echo "North London";
      } 
?>
```

But for some reason it is coming back blank.
Also this is perhaps not the best option as there are so many possibilities to query.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: In `substr`, you are extracting 3 characters and comparing the result to two characters.

Answer (score 1):

`substr(..., 0, 3)` extracts the first *three* characters, which will never equal `"N1"`. Change the `3` to a `2`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to make an array referenced by the first digits up to the dash.

```
<?php 
$postcode = get_zip(get_the_ID());
$postcodeTable = array(
    'N1' => "North London",
    'SW1' => "South West"
);

$start = explode('-', $postcode['id']);
echo $postcodeTable[$start[0]];
?>
```